# Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator for Android

Tags: c#, android, chatbot

Is there a Microsoft Bot Framework emulator for Android? Or is it possibile to communicate with the emulator through Android using something like REST? I'm not using the Azure portal, it's all working locally

Comment: Please anyone suggest me, Is there any bot emulator for android. I am using xamarin forms